# Multiple index match with variable path and filename to closed workbooks

Tags: excel, indexing, path, match, cells

I have a 'summary.xlsx' file which stores the status of several closed 'single report xlsx'.

The single reports have been stored on a file share. Each report is stored under a different folder, e.g. \MineServer\Reports\**ReportA**\**singleReport.xlsx** (the bold entries are variable).

In order to make the formula variable, I need to put the path & filename info into cells and then need to read it from there - I am getting always an error below:

> ('N/A,#value).

The formula which I am using does work in case I am hardcoding the path/filenames to the formula.
So the formula looks like =

```
{index('\\myServer\Reports\ReportA\
[singleReportA.xlsx]Report'!$E$2:$E$5,Match(1,('\\myServer\Reports\ReportA\
[singleReportA.xlsx]Report'!$B$2:$B$5=A76)*('\\myServer\Reports\ReportA\\ 
[singleReportA.xlsx]Report'!$C$2:$C$5=AA76),0))}
```

FYI: I need to grab the status of each single report from `$E$2:$E$5` where a name (A76 of my summary.xlsx) and a number (AA76 of my summary.xlsx) does match.

As mentioned earlier if I am hardcoding everything, then it works like a charm. However, if I put the relevant path & file names info to cells and trying to use

```
{=index("" BO13 & "[" B017 & "]" & B018 & "'!$E$2:$E$5", Match(
```

Then it does nt work.

I also tried the indirect.ext function, but unfortunately also without success.

I do really hope that somebody can give me a hint or even better can 'translate' the hardcorded formula into the variable formula - as I do not have any clue how I can get it work...

**EDIT**

Now I finally got it - at least almost. The formula looks like that now

```
`=INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU5),MATCH(A75,INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU7),0),MATCH(AA75,INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU8),0))`
```

The only issue is, I am not getting the right result set back.

Normally I would expect the results of column 5, but I am getting the cell info out of column 4 back.

What I am doing wrong?  What do I need to add to get the right column info?

Comment: Without `Indirect.Ext` you cannot dynamically create valid external worksheet/cells range references. No sense in trying. Your question may be more about why `Indirect.Ext` is not working or you could attempt a VBA solution or even a Data ► From Other Sources ► From Microsoft Query.

Comment: thanks, but why does it work without indirect.ext in case the path/file/sheet names are hardcoded to the formula???

Comment: It is like the difference between `=A1` and `="A1"`. The former is a valid cell address, the latter a text string that looks like a cell reference. You can hardcode a typed reference in just like you can type `=A1` but as soon as you start constructing a string by concatenating pieces together the result is a string that needs something like the [INDIRECT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to generate a usable cell reference. INDIRECT cannot handle external references but INDIRECT.Ext (a third-party add-on) can.

Comment: How many different BO13/B017/B018 references are there?

Comment: Got it! Only three of such references... Do you Know if indirect.ext would work in case i have to match 2 criteria?

Comment: [INDIRECT.Ext](http://1drv.ms/1FGgIdG) has nothing to do with how many (if any) criteria you have. It simply converts a constructed string to a usable external Workbook/Worksheet/Cell address. The rest of the formula is up to you but the external references *will* increase calculation load (as you've no doubt found out with the hardcoded references).

Comment: Now things are coming clear to me. your remark regarding the calc performance is clear to me as well.
Please correct me if I am wrong, but I thought the combination of index, indirect.ext and match won´t work, so how can I ensure that 2 criteria can be matched in the report xlsx and get the 'status' value of the same populated into my summary.xlsx?

Answer (score 0):

INDEX(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU5),MATCH(1,(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU7)=A75)*(INDIRECT.EXT("'"&BO13&"["&BO17&"]"&BO18&"'!"&BU8)=AA75),0))
This formula works as expected.